# In how many ways can $4$ subjects be chosen by $2$ students.....

Tags: combinatorics

I came across the following problem :

> In how many ways can $4$ subjects be chosen by $2$ students so that each student should take at least one subject?

I do not know how to tackle it.Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:
(If the subjects they choose is let to be same)

Number of choosing one subject by two students : 2$ 4\choose 1$

Number of choosing two subjects by two students: 2$4 \choose 2$

Number of choosing three subjects by two students: 2$ 4\choose 3$

Number of choosing Four subjects by two students: 2$4\choose 4$

Now add them all.

Answer (score 1):

As is all too often the case, there are many possible interpretations of the problem.  We will interpret the problem as meaning that there are two students, A and B, and they each may choose $1$ to $4$ subjects.

There are $2^4$ subsets of the set of courses, of which one is the empty set. So A has $15$ choices. For **every** choice by A, Student B has $15$ choices, for a total of $(15)^2$.